# Electric skateboard ESC and homemade battery pack

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, remote-control, batteries

I am building an electric skateboard and it requires an 80A ESC and 22.2V Li-po battery to run.
I found a video where a guy connected a bunch of 18650 Lithium Ion cells in series to form an equivalent voltage supply. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1D90heZ8z4s

To my understanding, the amperage of the cells must match the amperage of the ESC. A standard cell is 3.7V 10A (/20A) so how does this work? Does the amperage of my battery matter?

Apologies and thanks in advance. I am new to this.

Cheers,

Comment: This is quite the ambitious project for someone new to the field. Batteries are dangerous (or can be). A 10Ah battery can put out much more than 10A. Ah is a measure of capacity. (10 A for hour, or 600A for 1 minute?). Anyway, with all of that out of the way. All you need to do is keep your ESC rating higher than your battery ratings. If you have a 1kW motor and a 24V battery pack, you will need (assuming 100% efficiency) 42A from your batteries. In this case your ESC is fine. If you want to power 2 of those motors though, your ESC would melt and splode. Make sense?

Comment: The amperage which *actually flows through the system* must be less than the amperage of the ESCs, less than the amperage of the batteries, and less than the amperage of the motor. I'm not sure how you can work out how many amps actually flow.

Comment: @user253731 current draw can be estimated by the power of the motor (P) divided by the voltage of your battery pack (Vb) and your efficiency (e, 0-1.0, usually given in datasheet of the motor controller) or: P/(Vb*e). This of course depends on if the power of the motor is peak power or average power or what.